# Build error with Boost Interprocess SharedMemory

Tags: boost

In Boost::Interprocess "Creating maps in shared memory" [section](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_map)

there's a sample. In the sample, std::allocator is used with 2 params:

```
typedef allocator<ValueType, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> 
         ShmemAllocator;
```

But standard allocator template is like that:

```
template < class T > class allocator;
```

So, how can it be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A person in a forum helped me. Here's the answer:
The allocator used in the sample is not std::allocator, it is boost::interprocess::allocator.